# Where is a commercially usable dataset of temperature by zipcode by month?

Tags: dataset, zipcode, weather, temperature

Lots of web sites offer this data (see http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q="average+temperature"+by+zip+code) but I don't see the dataset they are using.

I looked at the national weather service for a bit (see for example http://www.rdc.noaa.gov/~foia/index.html#electronic), and didn't see it.  NWS is in the National Oceanic and Atmospheric Administration (NOAA).  NOAA links:

- http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/oa/climate/climatedata.html#monthly
- http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/oa/climate/research/cag3/explain.html.

It looks so close, but I still haven't found it.

Answer (score 3):

Used [NOAA](http://ols.nndc.noaa.gov/plolstore/plsql/olstore.prodspecific?prodnum=C00224-PUB-A0001) in the past to fantastic results. I believe they have daily and monthly dumps. Really a ton of information, but it's remarkably intesresting!

Comment: The national weather service is in NOAA.  I believe they have the info, but where?  Link?

Comment: Ah, you are saying to get a CD shipped from the page you linked or something?  Which dataset is the one you used?

Comment: I was able to find: a few dozen select cities for free, and a CD for $500.

Answer (score 1):

You can try at [NOAA website free data](http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/oa/mpp/freedata.html). Check out Global Summary of the Day.

Comment: I don't see "Global Summary of the Day" on that page.

Comment: :) You can't find it by searching the document, because the title is image. Move down to section "Free Data K" and follow the "1. Global Summary of the Day" link. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try the National Climatic Data Center's [Climate Data Online](http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web)

Answer (score 0):

The National Climatic Data Center does not have this data in the form you're looking for it. I even spoke with them to confirm.

However, you can purchase a data set of historical average and/or monthly temperature and precipitation by zip code and county for all US zip codes and counties [here](https://www.sideyardvineyard.com/weatherbyzip), the data set looks as follow:

[image: screenshot of data set]